# Function is trying to find a <div> but can't as it is display: none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a Tabs function below.

```
//Tabs ///
    $('.tabs').each(function() {
        var $tabs = $(this);
        $tabs.find('.section-body > div:not(:first-child)').hide().end().find('.section-head a:eq(0)').addClass('active').end().find('.section-head a').on('click', function() {
            $tabs.find('.section-head a').removeClass('active').end().find('.section-body > div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show().siblings().hide();
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="section tabs">
  <div class="section-head">
    <a>Section A</a>
    <a>Section B</a>
  </div>
  <div class="section-body">
    <div>
      <p>Section A</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Section B</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This working fine, however, I wanted to use a Grid System plugin inside it, the plugin is here: http://loai.directory/Loai%20Aptana/assets/js/grid-system.js

So in order to use the Grid system plugin, the HTML of the tabs will look as follows:

```
<div class="section tabs">
      <div class="section-head">
        <a>Section A</a>
        <a>Section B</a>
      </div>
      <div class="section-body">
        <div>
            <div class="grid" data-columns><!--Grid-->
              <div>Section</div>
              <div>Section</div>
              <div>Section</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="grid" data-columns><!--Grid-->
              <div>Section</div>
              <div>Section</div>
              <div>Section</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Once I do that, I start getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null` for a live preview, visit http://loai.directory/Loai%20Aptana/profile and inspect the elements / open the browser console to see it.

I spent hours trying to debug this and fix it. One of the things I have tried, is to remove the tabs JS function and then grid system worked!, so I knew it was something to do with both plugins aren't working nicely together.

After farther dubbing, I found that the Grid System is trying to find the `<div class="grid" data-columns>` so it can apply the effect to it, however, the tabs function has hidden the one that is inside the second tab div:

```
<div>
              <div class="grid" data-columns><!--Grid-->
                  <div>Section</div>
                  <div>Section</div>
                  <div>Section</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But, I mean the div is still in the DOM and therefor it should be accessible? What is wrong? how can I fix it?